# wp_head and wp_footer hook not working

Tags: wordpress

I have make one custom theme options plugin and following code put in plugin file

```
add_action( 'init', 'test_head_footer_init' );
function test_head_footer_init() {
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'childtheme_favicon'); 
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'childtheme_analytics');
}

function childtheme_favicon() {
        $shortname =  get_option('of_shortname'); 
        if (get_option($shortname . '_custom_favicon') != '') {
            echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="'.  get_option($shortname .'_custom_favicon')  .'"/>'."\n";
        }
}

function childtheme_analytics(){
    $shortname =  get_option('of_shortname');
    $output = get_option($shortname . '_google_analytics');
    if ( $output <> "" ) 
        echo stripslashes($output) . "\n";
}
```

When i have run my code and check in home url page head tag nothing is print. same in footer.

Can you please guide me what i have mistake..

Thanks in advance.

**ANSWER**

Above code is working fine, but in my plugin file I have added `if(is_admin())`
condition above this code. That's why my side this code didn't work. Now I have removed that and code working quite fine.

Comment: I tested your code in my plugin, and I can see output from the function (I added a test `echo 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';` after the if option in the `childtheme_favicon()` function). Did you actually choose any option in your options? Maybe that's why it's not showing.

Comment: I have some conman mistake made that's why it's not displayed. Thanks for guide me.

Comment: If you've found the answer please add it below, or edit your code and add it so if someone has similar issues, they can find it and use it :)

Comment: Above code is working fine but in my plugin file i have added if(is_admin())  condition above this code that's why my side this code not work.

Now i have removed that and code working quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use init action, those 2 can be run without it.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'childtheme_favicon'); 
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'childtheme_analytics');

function childtheme_favicon() {
        $shortname =  get_option('of_shortname'); 
        if (get_option($shortname . '_custom_favicon') != '') {
            echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="'.  get_option($shortname .'_custom_favicon')  .'"/>'."\n";
        }
}

function childtheme_analytics(){
    $shortname =  get_option('of_shortname');
    $output = get_option($shortname . '_google_analytics');
    if ( $output <> "" ) 
        echo stripslashes($output) . "\n";
}
```

Also u need to place it inside functions.php or plugin file. If u try to place it in header.php it wont work because code needs to run before wp_head hook fires or nothing will happen.

Comment: I have try without init function but still not working

Comment: If i have same code place in function.php file then it's working. but why it is not working in plugin file?

Comment: He's using a plugin and should use `init` hook if he wants to load his functions before any headers are being sent. The code he wrote works fine...